# Web server to develop on for a maven Struts 2 project and netbeans 7.4 IDE

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am developing a Java web app using `Netbeans 7.4`. My experiences with `Glassfish` and `Tomcat` are not quite well. For Glassfish, see for yourself here:-

[Netbeans 7.4 & Glassfish 4: package.ClassName cannot be cast to package.ClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257334/netbeans-7-4-glassfish-4-package-classname-cannot-be-cast-to-package-classnam)

Tomcat also sometimes gives me problems while redeploying my project after editing, Netbeans first shows an error, then tries to restart it, complains for port already occupied and I need to shut it down manually.

Is there a java server which is tightly integrated with netbeans, or a server which need not any manual restarts after every small change I made in my code?

Comment: Should I move to some other IDE, with better web server integration? Or should I use cargo maven plugin and vim editor instead of any IDE to code?

Comment: Looks like no one, on the stack, is developing web apps on java and netbeans these days.